# Gradle execute android tasks in specific order

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to merge Android gradle tasks into one and execute them **in a specific order**. 
`task.dependsOn` did not work for me for a list of tasks, neither did the `shouldRunAfter` method.

```
task buildAll {
    shouldRunAfter = ['clean', 'checkstyle', 'build']
}
```

What is the best way to run Android gradle tasks in specific order?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `doLast` in connection with `exec`. In this example we define `buildAll` task which executes clean, checkstyle, build and lint **in order - one after the other**.

```
 task buildAll {
     doLast {
         exec {
             commandLine "${getRootDir()}/gradlew", "clean", "checkstyle", "build", "lint"
         }
     }
 }
```

you can also use:

```
task buildAll {
     doLast {
         exec {
             commandLine "${getRootDir()}/gradlew", "clean"
         }
         exec {
             commandLine "${getRootDir()}/gradlew", "checkstyle"
         }
         exec {
             commandLine "${getRootDir()}/gradlew", "build"
         }
         exec {
             commandLine "${getRootDir()}/gradlew", "lint"
         }
     }
 }
```